# Android just switched the default text color with latest Support Library 22.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I updated my Android project to the latest everything (support library 22.1, sdk, etc).

Now the weirdest thing is happening. The default text color has changed.
It used to be a dark grey (see the screenshot as appearing from Android Studio).

[image]

But when I run my app in my genymotion emulator (2.4.0 - API 21), I get this:

[image]

Again, the only thing that I changed is the gradle. Is that a SDK bug or me who did something wrong?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
```

Comment: I dont think its bug might be they change the default colour .for power optimisation they might have done this in newr version you can change the text color not a big deal

Comment: apply black color manually in xml.

Comment: I agree that's a quick fix, but because there is a difference between android studio and the emulator to me that's a big issue. It would be a trial and error thing

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, in your theme, make sure you include the following line with your desired color:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/grey_700</item>
</style>
```